# fb:comments-count return wrong value

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I use

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://e-drpciv.ro/intrebare/963/></fb:comments-count>
```

I also try with quotes

```
<fb:comments-count href="http://e-drpciv.ro/intrebare/963/"></fb:comments-count>
```

and the return is always zero:

```
/**/ FB.__globalCallbacks.fdd5cbfe8aa94c({"data":[{"name":"index_link_stat_url","fql_result_set":[{"url":"http:\/\/e-drpciv.ro\/intrebare\/963\/","commentsbox_count":0}]}]});
```

Some other links report less comments than real.
Eg. http://e-drpciv.ro/intrebare/35 report only 3 comments

I need to update something in my code? Or is just a facebook issue and I need to wait?
This problem persist for two days.

Answer (score 0):

If someone shares someone else story it wouldn't show you the comments of that previous share in your /home, but when you query the fql to get comment_count of that object `"SELECT comment_info FROM photo WHERE object_id = 1234567890"` it will count you all comments from all shares, this is why when you query the /home with FB API you will find posts without comments but with the `SELECT ...` it will return you positive number of comment's count. i belive that there is some join to make or to can get only the current user.